# App Store URL with custom values

Tags: iphone, app-store, referrals

I have my app published in about 100 different places in my city. I'd like to create a differente QR code for each one of these 100 places, and therefore, to know how many downloads have got each one.

For example (with Angry Birds app):

- itunes.apple.com/es/app/angry-birds/id343200656?place=1
- itunes.apple.com/es/app/angry-birds/id343200656?place=2
- itunes.apple.com/es/app/angry-birds/id343200656?place=3
- ...

And after the app is installed, I know that "place 1" have got one more download.

I know this can be done in Android ... but I haven't found anything for Apple.

Thank you

Comment: This is not quite related to whether the OS is Android or iOS. You simply encode different URLs into the QR codes.

Comment: H2CO3 ... ok, I know how to do that :D  ... but after downloading a specific one ... how can I know that was downloaded ? That's my question!